# Get if the user has selected any new option from select in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I am using laravel backpack and in my update function there is a form which could be edited using `edit` button of laravel which calls the update function.

and in my form I have an `expiry_date` and a `month` field which helps my client to update the subscription of his user. All is working fine and here is the code of my update function:

```
public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
{

    date_default_timezone_set('asia/calcutta');
    $month = $request->month;
    $expiry = new Carbon($request->expiry_date);
    $expiry_date = $expiry->addMonths($month);            
    $request['expiry_date'] = $expiry_date;

    // your additional operations before save here
    $redirect_location = parent::updateCrud($request);
    // your additional operations after save here
    // use $this->data['entry'] or $this->crud->entry
    return $redirect_location;
}
```

**NOW THE PROBLEM IS:**

- whenever my client clicks on edit button and edits the fields other than `month` and clicks on update, it calculates the expiry date again but my client clicked the button to update some other details of his user.

I want to ask if there is any method or something which could help me in finding that :

*if* the user has clicked on `select of month` and has selected a option from the select then only execute the `adding month to expiry_date code` and if not then only update the details of the user without affecting the original expiry_date.

If this is not the way please help me in finding the correct way.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no body is answering the question.

I solved it by:

1) Allowing null values in months field.

2) And Setting a default value of month field to '0'.

Like this:

```
   'name' => 'month',
        'label' => "Months",
        'type' => 'select2_from_array',
        'options' => ['0' => '0','1' => '1', '3' => '3', '6' => '6', '12' => '12'],
        'allows_null' => true,
        'value' => '0'
        // 'allows_multiple' => true, // OPTIONAL; needs you to cast this to array in your model;
    ], 'update/create/both');
```

3) and then in update function I called the last value of the month if it is '0':

```
public function update(UpdateRequest $request) {
    date_default_timezone_set('asia/calcutta');
    $month = $request->month;
    if($month != 0)
    {
     $expiry = new Carbon($request->expiry_date);
    $expiry_date = $expiry->addMonths($month);            
    $request['expiry_date'] = $expiry_date;   
    }
    else
    {
        $retained_month  = Tag::find($request->id);
        $month = $retained_month->month;
        $request['month'] = $month;

    }


    // your additional operations before save here
    $redirect_location = parent::updateCrud($request);
    // your additional operations after save here
    // use $this->data['entry'] or $this->crud->entry
    return $redirect_location;
}
```

And this solved the problem!!
Thanks